# Java socket transfers large files (2g), and it will always be interrupted once during the transfer process

Tags: java, sockets

Using segmented file transmission, the sender sends a 2g file, it will always be interrupted once during the transmission process, and throw `java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 2`.

The sender continuously flushes the data in the loop, and the receiver continuously obtains the 003 messages and saves the received data locally.

If the file is small, no exception will be thrown.

**sender**:

```java
while ((i = fin.read(outBytes)) > 0) { // outbytes size 65536
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("003");
    long point = position * outBytes.length;
    dataOutputStream.writeLong(point); // 
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(i); 
    dataOutputStream.write(outBytes, 0, i);
    dataOutputStream.flush();
    position = position + 1;
}
```

**receive**:

```java
try {
        System.out.println(in.available());
        operate = in.readUTF(); //003
} catch (UTFDataFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("throw utfdataformatexception");
    return false;
}
...
case "003": {
    try (RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(enPath, "rw")) {
         
         long pos = in.readLong();
                        
         int inputSize = in.readInt();
         byte[] eoutBytes = new byte[inputSize];
         System.out.println(inputSize);
         in.read(eoutBytes);

         randomAccessFile.seek(pos);

         randomAccessFile.write(eoutBytes, 0, inputSize);
         pre = pos - inputSize;
         transferFile.setCur(pre);
     }
     return true;
}
```

**output**

```java
65536
65536
65536
65536
34171 // ???
0 // ???
throw utfdataformatexception
```

Why does this program throw `java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte` when transferring large files?

Comment: `DataOutputStream` is not the appropriate stream type for arbitrary byte data. (Prefer a `Writer` anyway for this much data.)

Comment: Try bittorrent, or its technique, which breaks up the file into fragments, transmits those separately, then reforms the complete file from the fragments, all done with high fault tolerance.

Comment: The problem was solved. It was caused by the unpacking problem. Readutf started reading from the wrong position and threw the exception. Now the problem is solved by `readfully(bte(3))` and `readfully(byte(inpusize))`

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by the unpacking problem. Readutf started reading from the wrong position and threw the exception